# Ionic 3 Button is not totally fixed at the footer and it moves while scrolling

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3, footer

I need to fix a button at the bottom of an ionic 3 project page.

The actual scss script works but the button is not totally fixed to the bottom, and it moves while scrolling.

Here is the sass script:

```
.fixedBtn{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 0;
}
```

I tried to use `flex`:

```
div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

But the result was as shown in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sssrfq), not the right behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this :

```
 <button ion-button primary class="fixedBtn">a</button>
```

out side of ion-content 
should be like

```
<ion-content>

 /** your content  */ 

</ion-content>

<button ion-button primary class="fixedBtn">a</button>
```

and in your sass file :

```
.fixedBtn{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed !important;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 0;
}
```